# How to print END block after processed output in AWK?

Tags: awk

When I execute:

```
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN{print "head"}{print $3|"head"}END{print "bottom"}' d16.txt
```

I got this:

```
head
bottom
3823
9386
7152
8137
1933
1137
3921
2585
9637
0626
```

instead I want this:

```
head
3823
9386
7152
8137
1933
1137
3921
2585
9637
0626
bottom
```

note `head` command, it's ok be there since if I use it after the whole awk command I will lose bottom string, but anyway it isn't behaving expected.

Comment: Remove the |"head".  It's printing the first 10 numbers before the END.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the need to call head, just add a condition:

```
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN{print "head"}NR<=10{print $3}END{print "bottom"}' d16.txt
```

Now you still only get the top 10 lines, without calling a separate program, and in the right order.

As others have mentioned in the comments, you can improve the efficiency by exiting after 10 lines, instead of reading the whole file:

```
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN{print "head"}{print $3}NR==10{exit}END{print "bottom"}' d16.txt
```

For a small file this won't have much effect but it would be worth using this approach on larger ones.

Comment: Possibly faster: `awk 'BEGIN{print"head"}1;NR>=10{exit}END{print"bottom"}'` This will skip reading through lines 11..END.